# List of non-printing characters for bash prompts

Tags: bash

I found a couple of documents listing some of the capabilities of the bash prompt with non-printing characters (e.g. \E[33;44m to print yellow text on blue background), but everywhere I look, I only find very specific examples, and no real explanation of those special characters, or a complete list of everything that is possible with those characters.

Sometimes, the examples use a \033[ prefix, and sometimes it's \E[, is there a difference between both?

So far, I know the following is possible :

Use color : \E[33;44m
Move the cursor to a specific place (10th line, 20th column) : \033[10;20H
Hide the cursor : \E[?25l
Show the cursor : \E[?25h

Are there other magic combinations? Where can I find a full list of those special characters and how to use them?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Sometimes, the examples use a \033[ prefix, and sometimes it's \E[, is there a difference between both?

*First layer:* The `\` is an "escape character" in [C](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_%28programming_language%29) and other programming languages. `\033` and `\x1B` are C-style octal and hexadecimal escapes for the [ASCII control character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII#ASCII_control_characters) `ESC` (hexadecimal byte 0x1B). `\e` and `\E` are part of C too and also mean the same `ESC` character, but are not as common.

Whichever of the above you use, the same `ESC` is going to be inserted, but `\e` is shorter to type than `\033`.

> Are there other magic combinations? Where can I find a full list of those special characters and how to use them?

*Second layer:* Similarly, the ASCII `ESC` is a prefix for [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) used by the [VT100](http://vt100.net/docs/vt102-ug/chapter5.html) terminal and its descendants. The codes available aren't up to `bash`, but to the specific terminal emulator you're using. Probably all support the codes defined in [ECMA-48](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-048.htm), but it's only a small subset.

The [Xterm control sequences](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html) page has an extensive list, but you'll want to look for documentation for whatever you're using, be it `gnome-terminal`, Konsole, [`rxvt`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/urxvt) or whatever. Some are [specific to Linux console (tty)](http://linux.die.net/man/4/console_codes).

Comment: Most graphical terminals emulators, with the exception of `rxvt`, are attempting to emulate Xterm (and set $TERM accordingly).

Comment: @grawity: True, but there are in fact differences between them, often in the details of things like setting terminal/tab titles, and each of them has a handful of things the others don't (or do differently).  Which is why I called the XTerm sequences a good start.

Comment: http://www.linuxselfhelp.com/howtos/Bash-Prompt/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO-6.html : This place seems to refer to ANSI Escape Sequences, which would imply there is some sort of standard. Is what is listed there pretty much supported on all (modern) terminal emulators, and is that list complete?

Comment: @Fred: ANSI X3.64 is a standard for terminal escape sequences; most terminal emulators implement a superset of it.  You can do quite a bit with it, but a fair amount of interesting stuff is outside the standard.

Comment: Excellent team work there. The original post + the edit make for a perfect answer. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed, but it means I'm getting credit for other people's work.  :(  The current answer is rather different from my original.

Comment: [Apple has a nice article about ANSI escape sequences](https://bitly.com/1dsARoK)